# Nested dictionary replacing previous value + key instead of appending

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working on vector space model, data set consists of 50 text files. Iterating through them splitting into words and saving them in dictionary. Now i want to use nested dictionary like:

```
dictionary = { {someword: {Doc1:23},{Doc21:2},{Doc34:3}},
{someword: {Doc1:23},{Doc21:2},{Doc34:3}},
{someword: {Doc1:23},{Doc21:2},{Doc34:3}}
 }
```

but when i am running my program it replaces not only the document but also it does not calculates frequency by adding that how many times 'someword' occurred in a particular document.

```
for iterator in range(1, 51):
    f = open(directory + str(iterator) + ext, "r")
    for line in f.read().lower().split():
        line = getwords(line)
        for word in line:
            if check(word, stopwords) == 0:
                if existence(word, terms, iterator) != 1:
                    terms[word] = {}
                    terms[word]["Doc"+str(iterator)] = 1
                else:
                    terms[word]["Doc"+str(iterator)] = int(terms[word]["Doc"+str(iterator)]) + 1

    f.close()
```

existence function is :

```
def existence(tok, diction, iteration):
    if tok in diction:
        temp = "Doc"+str(iteration)
        if temp in diction:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    else:
        return 0
```

Result Somewhat like this.

```
{'blunder': {'Doc1': 1}, 'by': {'Doc50': 1}, 'anton': {'Doc27': 1}, 'chekhov': {'Doc27': 1}, 'an': {'Doc50': 1}, 'illustration': {'Doc48': 1}, 'story': {'Doc48': 1}, 'author': {'Doc48': 1}, 'portrait'...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to know how many times each word appears in each file?  This is easily accomplished with a `defaultdict` of `Counter`s, courtesy of the collections module.

You've got the right idea I think, looping over the files, reading line by line and splitting into words.  It's the counting part you need help with.

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from string import punctuation

fnames = ['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt', '4.txt', '5.txt']

word_counter = defaultdict(Counter)
for fname in fnames:
    with open(fname, 'r') as txt:
        for line in txt:
            words = line.lower().strip().split()
            for word in words:
                word = word.strip(punctuation)
                if word:
                    word_counter[word][fname] += 1
```

The data look will like this inside `word_counter`:

```
{
    'within': {
        '1.txt': 2,
        },
    'we': {
        '1.txt': 3,
        '2.txt': 2,
        '3.txt': 2,
        '4.txt': 2,
        '5.txt': 4,
        },
    'do': {
        '1.txt': 7,
        '2.txt': 8,
        '3.txt': 8,
        '4.txt': 6,
        '5.txt': 5,
        },
    ...
    }
```

Comment: File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/VSM/vsm2.py", line 13, in <module>
    while not word[0].isalpha():
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: @AlphaHash That was probably caused by a word which had no alpha characters; all punctuation and/or numbers.  I've improved the code to handle that.  This code works using random text, as well as numbers, words with punctuation, and other edge cases I could think of, but you may still need to fine tune it to  meet your specific needs.